# Looking for assistance with passing multiple variables using POST command

Tags: php, post

I have the following code:

```
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row1['supervisiondate'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row1['level'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row1['division'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row1['supervisor'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row1['totalscore'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<form action='refereesupervision.php' method='post'>";
                    echo "<td>
                    <input name='refereeID' value='" . $row['refereeID'] . "'/>
                    <input name='supervisionID' value='" . $row1['supervisionID'] . "'/>
                    <input type='submit' value='View'/>";
                    echo "</form></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }  </br>
```

When refereesupervision.php receives the data using post for each of the two variables, only the refereeID is received.  It should be noted that there are two separate queries of two separate tables that produce $row and $row1.

Looking for some guidance or references to help me understand.

Cheers

Comment: Could you please post your code where you receive the data?

Comment: Here you are:  `<?php
 require_once('auth.php');
 //Include database connection details
 require_once ('connection.php');
 $supervisionID = $_POST["supervisionID"];
 $refereeid = $_POST["refereeID"];
 echo "$refereeID";
 echo "$supervisionID";
 
?>`

Comment: Your name of input is `ID` not `supervisionID`

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I pasted the wrong code.  I have updated the post to what I currently have and I am still having the same problem.

Comment: After submit use `var_dump( $_POST );` to see what happend

Comment: I have been staring at this for too long, it is the refereeID that is not being passed as per this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: refereeID in D:\Webs\OLASupervision\php2\refereesupervision.php on line 8`. And I should add that the table is showing both the refereeID and supervisionID.

Comment: again `$refereeID` is not the same as `$refereeid`;

Comment: @trzyeM-when I placed that code in the receiving page I received this: `array(2) { ["refereeID"]=> string(1) "1" ["supervisionID"]=> string(1) "2" } `.

Comment: As You can see after submit form send OK. Both variable have value as You want.

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

according to comment change input name from ID to supervisionID

`<input name='ID' value='" . $row1['supervisionID'] . "'/>`

`<input name='supervisionID' value='" . $row1['supervisionID'] . "'/>`

According to comments and editing original question. Answer is
`$refereeID` is not the same as `$refereeid`